# Optional chaining not work inside v-if Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i've tried to **Optional Chaining** my `v-if` condition like these

```
.sidebar(v-if="foo?.slug")
```

the previous one was like this

```
.sidebar(v-if="foo && foo.slug")
```

its works fine using this, but if i using optional chaining, it show error/not work

any solution guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6307#issuecomment-493339386).

Comment: You can also see this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11088#issuecomment-629161798) related to optional chaining not working in templates.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that optional chaining syntax (the `?.` operator) is not supported in `Vue.js 2` templates. This is because `Vue.js` templates use a different syntax from regular `JavaScript`, and the `?.` operator is not part of that syntax.

However, you can still achieve similar functionality by using a computed property in your component that checks if a property is defined before accessing it. For example:

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        {{ computedProperty }}
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          obj: {
            prop: 'value'
          }
        }
      },
      computed: {
        computedProperty() {
          return this.obj.prop?.toUpperCase()
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Vue 3 supports optional chaining syntax  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027463/15794828