# Vue3 use OpenAI node Library Error:"Unexpected token"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, openai-api

I want to use Openai API Node Library in my Vue3 project, so I did the following steps:

1. I type this command in my VScode terminal.

```
npm install openai
```

2. I add `import OpenAI from "openai"` into my code area <script setup> </script>.
3. Then I type `npm run serve` in my VScode terminal.
4. Then I get this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                         20:47:19

 error  in ./node_modules/openai/index.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (50:148)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|      * @param {boolean} [opts.dangerouslyAllowBrowser=false] - By default, client-side use of this library is not allowed, as it risks exposing your secret API credentials to attackers.
|      */
>     constructor({ baseURL = Core.readEnv('OPENAI_BASE_URL'), apiKey = Core.readEnv('OPENAI_API_KEY'), organization = Core.readEnv('OPENAI_ORG_ID') ?? null, ...opts } = {}) {
|         if (apiKey === undefined) {
|             throw new Errors.OpenAIError("The OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable is missing or empty; either provide it, or instantiate the OpenAI client with an apiKey option, like new OpenAI({ apiKey: 'My API Key' }).");

 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/ToolsViews/LLMModelDetails.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js 20:0-28 131:15-21
 @ ./src/ToolsViews/LLMModelDetails.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js
 @ ./src/ToolsViews/LLMModelDetails.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.7:8090&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

````
My `package.json`:

```json


{

  "name": "vue-argon-dashboard-2",

  "version": "3.0.0",

  "private": true,

  "author": "Creative Tim",

  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <https://www.creative-tim.com/license>",

  "description": "VueJS version of Argon Dashboard 2 by Creative Tim",

  "homepage": "https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-argon-dashboard/",

  "bugs": {

    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-argon-dashboard/issues"

  },

  "repository": {

    "type": "git",

    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-argon-dashboard.git"

  },

  "scripts": {

    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",

    "build": "vue-cli-service build",

    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"

  },

  "dependencies": {

    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",

    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^0.8.1",

    "@popperjs/core": "2.11.8",

    "axios": "^1.6.5",

    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",

    "core-js": "3.35.1",

    "dropzone": "6.0.0-beta.2",

    "echarts": "^4.9.0",

    "element-plus": "^2.5.2",

    "jquery": "^3.7.1",

    "next": "^14.1.0",

    "openai": "^4.28.0",

    "pinia": "^2.1.7",

    "quill": "1.3.7",

    "vue": "3.4.15",

    "vue-flatpickr-component": "11.0.3",

    "vue-router": "4.2.5",

    "vuex": "^4.1.0"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",

    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",

    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "4.5.0",

    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "4.5.0",

    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "4.5.0",

    "@vue/cli-service": "4.5.0",

    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "3.2.0",

    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "6.0.0",

    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",

    "eslint": "6.7.2",

    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.3.1",

    "eslint-plugin-vue": "7.0.0",

    "prettier": "2.2.1",

    "sass": "1.43.3",

    "sass-loader": "10.1.1"

  }

}
````

My `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {

  lintOnSave: false,//关闭eslint语法检查

  devServer: {

    port: 8090,

    proxy: {

      '/api': {

        // target: 'http://localhost:9088',

        target: 'http://localhost:9172',

        changeOrigin: true,

        ws: true,

        pathRewrite: {

          // '^/api'是一个正则表达式，表示要匹配请求的url中，全部'http://localhost:8000/api' 转接为 http://localhost:8000/

          '^/api': '',

        }

      }

    }

  },

  configureWebpack: {

    module: {

      rules: [

        {

          test: /\.mjs$/,

          include: /node_modules/,

          type: "javascript/auto"

        }

      ]

    }

  }

};
```

My babel.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset","@babel/preset-env"],

};
```

I tried to upgrade my Node to the latest version,but nothing changed.And I created another project that only use OpenAI API Node library, and this project works well!So I am confused...

After I type `npm uninstall openai` and detele `import OpenAI from "openai"` from my code, my project works well, I don't know the reasons why this happen.

I have tried to fix this error for the passed 6 hours and I failed, could anyone help me please?

Comment: Vue CLI is old, `?? null` and possibly other features are not supported. See related questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61770909/support-optional-chaining-in-vuejs

Comment: Yes, you are right. My Vue Cli is too old to support operator `??`. I installed `Openai@4.11.1`  and the problem solved.